# Transfer Old 32-bit Project to 64 bit in Xcode 9.3 with 32bit target

Tags: c++, c, xcode, architecture

as the title mentioned, Here are errors thrown from target who uses 32-bit library and the screenshot of Architectures of this target. I do not know where it is going wrong. Thank you for all possible help! I am in Mojave MacOSX. In order to build old 32-bit, I changed architectures of other target to 64 bit and there is no error for them while building. But for one target which is something like SWIG interface using python in C/C++. 
[enter image description here][1]

````
    cd "/Users/zhouyuhongze/Downloads/cove_dev copy-64-9.3"
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++-header -arch ppc -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -gmodules -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DMAC -DUWWF_EXPORTS -isysroot /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -g -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-move -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-range-loop-analysis -index-store-path /Users/zhouyuhongze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cove-brktkbotsuuztjcusjhbbaohvtrb/Index/DataStore -I/Users/zhouyuhongze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cove-brktkbotsuuztjcusjhbbaohvtrb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/cove.build/Debug/uwwf_python.build/_uwwf_python.hmap -I/Users/zhouyuhongze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cove-brktkbotsuuztjcusjhbbaohvtrb/Build/Products/Debug/include -Ibase -Ibase/vl/include -Iidv -Ilib/fltk -Ilib/netcdf -I/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/Users/zhouyuhongze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cove-brktkbotsuuztjcusjhbbaohvtrb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/cove.build/Debug/uwwf_python.build/DerivedSources/ppc -I/Users/zhouyuhongze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cove-brktkbotsuuztjcusjhbbaohvtrb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/cove.build/Debug/uwwf_python.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/zhouyuhongze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cove-brktkbotsuuztjcusjhbbaohvtrb/Build/Products/Debug -MD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/zhouyuhongze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cove-brktkbotsuuztjcusjhbbaohvtrb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/cove_Prefix-gvxvqsoycewanvflcbunhiimhfnz/cove_Prefix.pch.d -c /Users/zhouyuhongze/Downloads/cove_dev\ copy-64-9.3/cove_Prefix.pch -o /Users/zhouyuhongze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cove-brktkbotsuuztjcusjhbbaohvtrb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/cove_Prefix-gvxvqsoycewanvflcbunhiimhfnz/cove_Prefix.pch.pch --serialize-diagnostics /Users/zhouyuhongze/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cove-brktkbotsuuztjcusjhbbaohvtrb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/cove_Prefix-gvxvqsoycewanvflcbunhiimhfnz/cove_Prefix.pch.dia

In file included from /Users/zhouyuhongze/Downloads/cove_dev copy-64-9.3/cove_Prefix.pch:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:75:
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:763:2: error: Unsupported architecture
#error Unsupported architecture
 ^
In file included from /Users/zhouyuhongze/Downloads/cove_dev copy-64-9.3/cove_Prefix.pch:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:78:
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from /Users/zhouyuhongze/Downloads/cove_dev copy-64-9.3/cove_Prefix.pch:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:79:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from /Users/zhouyuhongze/Downloads/cove_dev copy-64-9.3/cove_Prefix.pch:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:79:
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'
typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'
typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
        ^
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'
typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
        ^
In file included from /Users/zhouyuhongze/Downloads/cove_dev copy-64-9.3/cove_Prefix.pch:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:81:
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/machine/endian.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
#error architecture not supported
 ^
In file included from /Users/zhouyuhongze/Downloads/cove_dev copy-64-9.3/cove_Prefix.pch:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:
/Applications/Xcode9.3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/usr/include/sys/types.h:95:9: error: unknown type name 'u_int64_t'
typedef u_int64_t               u_quad_t;       /* quads */
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmnLG.png
````

Comment: Image Link is below.

Comment: the same for me